# The Level of the Universal Central Extension of a Loop Group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, infinite-groups

I understand that when $G$ is a compact, connected, simple and simply connected Lie group, there is a universal central extension of the loop group $LG$, which is denoted as $\widetilde{LG}$.

My question is regarding Proposition (9.3.9) in 'Loop Groups' by Andrew Pressley and Graeme Segal. I do not understand all the details in this proposition, but it seems like they are trying to say that, when $G$ is also simply laced, all irreducible representations of $\widetilde{LG}$ are obtainable from irreducible representations of $\widetilde{LG}$ of level one. So it seems to me that irreducible representations of $\widetilde{LG}$ effectively always have level one. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know what "effectively" means here. It's certainly not true that irreps always have level one. The procedure Pressley-Segal describes for obtaining irreps doesn't preserve level.

Comment: @Qiaochu: What I meant by "effectively" is that it seemed that irreps of any level can be obtained from irreps of level one. So irreps of level one are in some sense 'universal'.  What do you think? Sorry if I sound ridiculous, but I'm a naive physicist. :)